# Image becomes black when exporting from the Figma to Android Studo

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack, figma

I have a Figma Design and I want to convert it to Kotlin Jetpack Design in the android Studio.

However, I am having an issue when export an illustration from Figma as image and add it Android Studio as drawable. When I fire up the emulator, all the image colors becomes black.

Please see the image below for the view from Figma and Android Studio.

[Image from Figma and Image observed in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl6JG.png)

Could you please help me to solve this issue?

P.S.

Thanks.

I have tried png and jpeg formats but both of them shows same issue.

I copied the image as Png in Figma and past it to Paint, then saved it to use it in Android Emulator but the same issue happened.

Comment: It may be pointless to add a screenshot into an app, because the navigation editor makes Figma redundant. https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039825114-Color-management-in-the-desktop-app

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue when exporting from Figma in Flutter.

The solution for me was to use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg and download the images as SVG's.

```
SvgPicture.asset(assetName)
```